# Python pretty printer or pdf merger

Tags: python, pdf, libreoffice

I have a reasonably large piece of code that i need to put into a document,

currently I have my source code and an LibreOffice file.

Does anyone know of a pretty printer (eg colour text) for python code or alternatively a way to merge pdf documents (as i know how to pretty print to pdf)?

EDIT: my requirements for output are really just to attach the source code to the bottom of the document in a way thats more readable than just straight black text

Comment: You can't really sanely merge PDF documents - at best you can splice pages together. (That is, short of using fairly expensive software capable of reflowing an existing PDF.)

Comment: Also [Pygments](http://pygments.org/). That said it would help if we knew what your requirements on the output format are.

Comment: sure you can merge pdf documents, at worst you could make a latex document to do that, but that's really an overkill..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this shell command lets you merge pdf files

```
gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=output.pdf file1.pdf file2.pdf file3.pdf
```

Comment: thanks that does just what i need